# How to get particular post's detail via WP Rest Api?

Tags: android, wordpress, api, rest

I want to fetch a particular post by URL using rest API in WordPress, but I don't know if that is possible.

With JSON, I can fetch using this code

```
https://www.punjabidharti.com/punjabi-kahaniya/sir-da-sai/?json=get_post
```

Is there similar code available for WordPress Rest API also?

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieve a Post

```
GET /wp/v2/posts/<id>
```

Query this endpoint to retrieve a specific post record.

```
$ curl https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<id>
```

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#retrieve-a-post

| Argument | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `id` | Unique identifier for the object. |
| `context` | Scope under which the request is made; determines fields present in response. Default: `view`; One of: `view`, `embed`, `edit`; |
| `password` | The password for the post if it is password protected. |